# Convert String to Socket

Tags: java, json, string, sockets

I saved sockets in a Json object but when I read the socket, cannot use it because is a String value, this is the code:

```
String socket1 =nombre.getAsJsonObject().get("socket").getAsString();
```

I can convert that String value to Socket?

Comment: Um, you can't. A socket is a connection to another computer... you can't just manufacturer it again. What's the context here? Why are you using JSON at all here? You could have some sort of map from a socket "ID" (which you'd need to invent) to a socket, and just put the ID in the JSON... but it would be quite odd.

Answer (score -3):

if you have a very simple string you can do

```
socket.getOutputStream().write("your string".getBytes("US-ASCII"));
```

Also you can use Buffer Array or

```
res = new Buffer("your String");
```

Comment: You don't appear to have read the question. You certainly haven't answered it.

Comment: This answer seems to be unrelated to the (real) question.